# DFA for all words that contain an even number of 0's and whose number of 1's is divisible by 3

Tags: dfa

I am really trying to solve this one but it seems quite imppossbile for me. Can someone show me ?

Answer (score 0):

So here's an idea:

[image]

States E2, E1 and E0 indicate an even number of 0s and the remainder of the division of the number of 1s with 3 e.g. E2 means even 0s and (number of 1s)mod3=2

If you get a 0 you jump from E to the corresponding O and vice versa.

If you get a 1 you go to the next remainder starting from 0 - 2 - 1 and cycle.

The accepting state is even 0s and (number of 1s)mod 3 = 0